# MySqlConnection Parameters cutting off data at 200bytes

Tags: c#, mysql, parameters

I am using mySQL with .net 4.5 to do typical CRUD commands.

I have an issue wit a parameter which is called 'Message' (Chat application). It seems the text inserted into the database is being cut off at 200 bytes.

I have tried multiple data types for the column. Currently it is TEXT, I have tried LONGTEXT and varchar(1000) etc; but still, it gets cut off at 200 bytes.

What is going on?

```
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString());             
            conn.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            cmd.CommandText = "createStaffMessage";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sessionID", sessionID);
            cmd.Parameters["@sessionID"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@chatID", chatId);
            cmd.Parameters["@chatID"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@message", message);
            cmd.Parameters["@message"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@byStaff", byStaff);
            cmd.Parameters["@byStaff"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@staffId", staffId);
            cmd.Parameters["@staffId"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateTimeString", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + " (NZ Time)");
            cmd.Parameters["@dateTimeString"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            rdr.Read();
            string[] newMessageDetails = new string[2];
            newMessageDetails[0] = rdr[0].ToString();
            newMessageDetails[1] = rdr[1].ToString();
            conn.Close();
            return newMessageDetails;
```

Comment: Please show the stored procedure code. In particular the declaration of the parameters received by the stored procedure

Comment: Thanks Steve, that was it. I forgot to change my stored procedure parameter to text from varchar(200) hence why it was getting cut off.

Comment: Yes that was the suspect